# Auth0: Add login_hint query param to redirect URL after password change

Tags: authentication, auth0, auth0-lock, auth0-delegated-admin, auth0-connection

Is there a way to add the `login_hint` query params along with `iss` query params in URL received after password-change?

Detail Use case: A password change ticket email will be sent to the user. The user clicks on the `change password URL`, and changes the password. Then after the successful message, the user clicks on the `back to` button. The user is redirected to the auth0 login page via redirection from the app. On reaching the app (redirect URL), only the `iss` query param is appended in the URL. Is there a way to append `login_hint` query params too? So that the `/authorize` endpoint hit via the app will automatically append `login_hint` and the email field will get auto-populated?